# Java creating objects for different arguments

Tags: java, object, design-patterns

is there any way to create objects for the same model which is calling again and again. Or any best practice even design pattern. Note- Cannot take map

Example-

```
**MothlyData** mdapril = dao.getData("April");
**MothlyData** mdmay = dao.getData("May");
**MothlyData** mdjune = dao.getData("June");
**MothlyData** mdajuly = dao.getData("July");
**MothlyData** mdaaug = dao.getData("Aug");
**MothlyData** mdasept = dao.getData("Sept");
```

Comment: You could use a switch statement. Why can't you use a map?

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting, if you don't want to use a map then you will need 6 different objects or?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm